# How to level the height of items in LazyVerticalGrid?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

I'm using `LazyVerticalGrid` to display list of items.

```
LazyVerticalGrid(
            cells = GridCells.Fixed(2),
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
            state = listState,
            content = {
                    Box(modifier = boxModifier) {
                        ProductItemView(
                            item = items[index]
                        )
                    }
                }
            }
        )
```

Sometimes some of my items are higher than the items next to them (attachemnt)
[image]

How can I adjust the height of the all items? Or should I use something other than `VerticalGrid`()?

Comment: Have you tried this with version 1.2.0-alpha05 of Jetpack Compose, they have just made LazyVerticalGrid stable. If it still persists It might be a good idea to raise it as a bug

Comment: @James i have a similar problem and still persists with compose version 1.2.0-alpha07

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you give a fixed height to your Composables you might end up Composables that don't display some part of your child composables, in your case it might be `Text` composable.

First and easy way is to set a minimum height `Modifier.heightIn(min = 200.dp)`, this might leave space below or above your composable depending on your Box alignment, and if your Composables are taller than 200.dp it will have the same effect you have now, so it's not or adding any fixed height is not enough.

Better way is to use onTextLayout to get Text's line count and height to add smaller number of lines as padding as

```
@Composable
fun GridSnackCardWithTitle(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    snack: Snack,
) {
    Column(
        modifier = modifier
            .heightIn(min = 200.dp)
            .shadow(1.dp, shape = RoundedCornerShape(5.dp))
            .background(Color.White),

        ) {

        val density = LocalDensity.current.density

        Image(
            contentScale = ContentScale.None,
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .aspectRatio(1f)
                .clip(RoundedCornerShape(8.dp))
                .clickable { },
            painter = rememberImagePainter(
                data = snack.imageUrl,
                builder = {
                    placeholder(drawableResId = R.drawable.placeholder)
                }
            ),
            contentDescription = null
        )

        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(4.dp))
        var padding by remember { mutableStateOf(0.dp) }
        Text(
            modifier = Modifier.padding(start = 4.dp, end = 4.dp, bottom = padding),
            text = "Snack ${snack.name}",
            fontSize = 20.sp,
            onTextLayout = {
                val lineCount = it.lineCount
                val height = (it.size.height / density).dp

                println("lineCount: $lineCount, Height: $height")
                padding = if (lineCount > 1) 0.dp else height
            }
        )
        
    }
}
```

Result

[image]

Comment: how can i use this method if instead of a single `Text` at the bottom, i have a column with multiple `Text`s?

Comment: Were you able to use it with multiple texts? @or_dvir?

Comment: @ysfcyln unfortunately not

Comment: @or_dvir you can find height of each `Text ` using `onTextLayout` and set it as maximum padding. If  you have one `Text ` with multiple lines text you can do the same.

Comment: this will add extra padding to ALL items in grid, not only to items in one row

Comment: Other option is to track   `state.layoutInfo.visibleItemsInfo` and check if items that are visible in which columns and based on that use Modifier.onPlaced to set items in each row to same height

Comment: Other option is to measure every text, if they are Text composable, with textMeasurer and map them as in first option then set each rows padding based on these. If they are not Text composables then option is to use SubcomposeLayout

Answer (score 2):

Usually such problem is solved by adding `Modifier.fillMaxHeight` to containing items, and `Modifier.height(IntrinsicSize.Max)` to the container.

The problem is that in this case we don't have access to the container `Modifier`: in Compose **1.1.*** there's a `Row` in the source code, but we cannot pass our modifier down to it, and in **1.2.*** there's no `Row` at all.

I think such a request is fair, but for now you can do it yourself in `LazyColumn`:

```
val columnsCount = 2
val itemsCount = 10
LazyColumn(
    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()
) {
    items((itemsCount + 1) / columnsCount) { i ->
        Row(Modifier.height(IntrinsicSize.Max)) {
            for (j in 0 until columnsCount) {
                val index = i * columnsCount + j
                if (index < itemsCount) {
                    Text(
                        LoremIpsum(index).values.first(),
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .fillMaxHeight()
                            .weight(1f)
                            .background(
                                when (index % 3) {
                                    0 -> Color.LightGray
                                    1 -> Color.DarkGray
                                    else -> Color.Gray
                                }
                            )
                    )
                } else {
                    Spacer(Modifier.weight(1f))
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Works really well. However, I did find that if you want more than 2 columns - or to change the column count dynamically, this line:

`items((itemsCount + 1) / columnCount) {`

needs to instead be:

`items((itemsCount + (columnCount - 1)) / columnCount) {`

Otherwise, you end up elements missing from the grid. Hope that helps people!

Answer (score -2):

What's happening is which ever item has text larger than one line, it expands

To keep a uniform height, you have to set a minimum height to every child `Box`, to do so, you can use the `Modifier` as below.

```
//Adjust 200.dp as your requirement
Box(modifier = Modifier.height(200.dp))
```

This way, every box will have same height irrespective of the length/size of the content.

Comment: you say to set MINIMUM height, but you are setting a FIXED height. what if the length of the text makes it such that the box's height is greater than 200dp? the text will be cut-off