# How to make all the items in the **LazyVerticalGrid** to the same height without hardcoding height?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I referred this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71479946/20918983), but in my case I cannot hardcode the item height. Is there any solution without fixing the height?

*I want items 1 and 2 to be the same height as item 0.*

[image: output of the below code]

Please refer to the below code.

```
@Composable
fun LazyVerticalGridDemo() {
val list = (1..10).map { it.toString() }

LazyVerticalGrid(columns = GridCells.Adaptive(128.dp),

    // content padding
    contentPadding = PaddingValues(
        start = 12.dp, top = 16.dp, end = 12.dp, bottom = 16.dp
    ), content = {

        item {
            Card(
                backgroundColor = Color.Blue,
                modifier = Modifier
                    .padding(4.dp)
                    .fillMaxWidth(),
                elevation = 8.dp,
            ) {
                Text(
                    text = "0",
                    fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold,
                    fontSize = 30.sp,
                    color = Color(0xFFFFFFFF),
                    textAlign = TextAlign.Center,
                    modifier = Modifier.padding(24.dp)
                )
            }
        }

        items(list.size) { index ->
            Card(
                backgroundColor = Color.Red,
                modifier = Modifier
                    .padding(4.dp)
                    .fillMaxWidth(),
                elevation = 8.dp,
            ) {
                Text(
                    text = list[index],
                    fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold,
                    fontSize = 30.sp,
                    color = Color(0xFFFFFFFF),
                    textAlign = TextAlign.Center,
                    modifier = Modifier.padding(16.dp)
                )
            }
        }
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can save the **height** and density using

```
var height by remember { mutableStateOf(0.dp) }
val density = LocalDensity.current
```

and then observe the size change from modifier

```
.onSizeChanged { if(height == 0.dp) { height = with(density) { it.height.toDp() } }}
```

apply this calculated **height** on you next item in **LazyVerticalGrid**.

Full code

```kotlin
@Composable
fun LazyVerticalGridDemo() {
    val list = (1..10).map { it.toString() }
    var height by remember { mutableStateOf(0.dp) }
    val density = LocalDensity.current
    LazyVerticalGrid(
        columns = GridCells.Adaptive(128.dp),

        // content padding
        contentPadding = PaddingValues(
            start = 12.dp,
            top = 16.dp,
            end = 12.dp,
            bottom = 16.dp
        ),
        content = {
            item {
                Card(
                    backgroundColor = Color.Blue,
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .padding(4.dp)
                        .fillMaxWidth().onSizeChanged {
                            if (height == 0.dp) {
                                height = with(density) { it.height.toDp() }
                            }
                        },
                    elevation = 8.dp
                ) {
                    Text(
                        text = "0",
                        fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold,
                        fontSize = 30.sp,
                        color = Color(0xFFFFFFFF),
                        textAlign = TextAlign.Center,
                        modifier = Modifier.padding(24.dp)
                    )
                }
            }

            items(list.size) { index ->
                Card(
                    backgroundColor = Color.Red,
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .padding(4.dp)
                        .fillMaxWidth().height(height),
                    elevation = 8.dp
                ) {
                    Text(
                        text = list[index],
                        fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold,
                        fontSize = 30.sp,
                        color = Color(0xFFFFFFFF),
                        textAlign = TextAlign.Center,
                        modifier = Modifier.padding(16.dp)
                    )
                }
            }
        }
    )
}
```