# How to have grid items same height in row for LazyVerticalGrid Android Compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I have a similar problem to [How to level the height of items in LazyVerticalGrid?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70325468/how-to-level-the-height-of-items-in-lazyverticalgrid).

My grid item is basically a column with an image and text beneath. If the text wraps to 2 lines, then there will be uneven heights.

I want so that if the height is uneven in a row, have all items in that row to be the same height.

The current answer for the post link above adds padding to all items in the grid so that they are all equal. But I want only the necessary items to be the same height rather than add unnecessary padding to all items.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to do that.

- Consider replacing the parent of the component with a custom layout which controls the order in which children are measured.
- Adding a size modifier to the component.