# Fill remaining space in LazyVerticalGrid Item

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I am using a LazyVerticalGrid to display items with dynamic content, but i want to have the same height always, regardless of item size. ¿how to achieve this? Right now even when the column include fillMaxHeight modifier the result is the same.

```
@Composable
fun VerticalGrid() {
    val products = listOf(
        Product("Product 11111111111111", "100"),
        Product("Product 2222222222222222", "200"),
        Product("Product 3", "300"),
        Product("Product 4", "400"),
        Product("Product 5", "500"),
        Product("Product 6", "600"),
        Product("Product 7", "700"),
        Product("Product 8", "800")
    )
    LazyVerticalGrid(
        cells = GridCells.Fixed(2),
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(dimensionResource(R.dimen.size_small)),
        horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(dimensionResource(R.dimen.size_small)),
        modifier = Modifier.background(colorResource(id = R.color.light_gray_background))
    ) {
        itemsIndexed(products) { _, item ->
            Column(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .background(Color.White)
                    .padding(16.dp)
                    .fillMaxHeight()
            ) {
                Text(text = item.title)
                Text(text = item.price)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: The easiest way is to make sure your "Product n" line doesn't wrap. You can add `maxLines = 1, overflow = TextOverflow.Clip` to the `Text`.

Comment: I do have to display the content,so thats not a solution :(

Comment: check this:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70325468/how-to-level-the-height-of-items-in-lazyverticalgrid

Comment: just add fixed height of the composable will solve your problem

Comment: Modifier.height(210.dp) like this

Answer (score -1):

Change LazyVerticalGrid to LazyVerticalStaggeredGrid

https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/lists#lazy-staggered-grid

```
LazyVerticalStaggeredGrid(
columns = StaggeredGridCells.Adaptive(200.dp),
verticalItemSpacing = 4.dp,
horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(4.dp),
content = {
    items(randomSizedPhotos) { photo ->
        AsyncImage(
            model = photo,
            contentScale = ContentScale.Crop,
            contentDescription = null,
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth().wrapContentHeight()
        )
    }
},
modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()
```

)

Comment: That won't keep the same height to all the items. I just want to fill that empty space, so the bottom is exactly at she same height of the second item